# My node.js-powered app can only be accessed from some remote clients but not others. How can I get all clients to access it?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am developing a multi-user, interactive, game-like collective behavior experiment that uses node.js, socket.io, and express.  The site for it is:
http://pcl.cogs.indiana.edu:8080/
When I am at my university, the same university where the server is deployed, or when I am elsewhere but first VPN into my university, the site works fine and I am immediately put into the experiment.  When I am not at my university and don’t VPN in, usually Chrome spins around for awhile and then eventually delivers the error message:

This site can’t be reached
pcl.cogs.indiana.edu took too long to respond.

ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

When I am away from my university and don’t VPN in,  the site still sometimes works, perhaps depending on how the client’s network is set up?  How do I troubleshoot where the problem is?  That is, how do I figure out if the problem is with the network settings at the client end, or at the server end at my university?  Is there a way to inspect some log that tells me what clients attempted to reach the server but were rejected?  Most pragmatically, what kinds of fixes should I be looking at in my server code or server settings that will let all remote clients into the experiment?  I’m including the beginning of my app.js code in case that helps:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require("fs");
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});


app.set('view engine', 'pug');

const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

if (module === require.main) {
  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
  server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
    console.log('Press Ctrl+C to quit.');
  });
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it's accessible from outside your university's network, and not perhaps your browser cache (when it works intermittently)? Got alot of hoops to jump through before being routed to a particular machine through a common firewalled port, especially on a closed network like a university.

Comment: I asked somebody else from another institution to try accessing the experiment, and they were able to do it.  But other people from other institution can't.  But I want all (or most) institutions to be able to access it, so I'm hoping/figuring that there's something that can be done on my server side to make it play with more clients.